# Javascript object/array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Struggling with some javascript array manipulation/updating. Hope someone could help.

I have an array:

```
 array('saved_designs'=array());
```

Javascript JSON version:

```
 {"saved_design":{}}
```

I will be adding a label, and associated array data:

```
 array("saved_designs"=array('label'=array('class'='somecssclass',styles=array(ill add more assoc elements here),'hover'=array(ill add more assoc elements here))))
```

Javascript version:

```
 {"saved_designs":{"label":{"class":"someclass","style":[],"hover":[]}}}
```

I want to be able to append/modify this array. If 'label' already defined...then cycle through the sub data for that element...and update. If 'label' doesnt exist..then append a new data set to the 'saved_designs' array element.

So, if label is not defined, add the following to the 'saved_designs' element:

```
 array('label2' = array('class'=>'someclass2',styles=array(),'hover=>array()')
```

Things arent quite working out as i expect. Im unsure of the javascript notation of [], and {}  and the differences.

Probably going to need to discuss this as answers are provided....but heres some code i have at the moment to achive this:

```
 //saveLabel = label the user chose for this "design"
 if(isUnique == 0){//update
      //ask user if want to overwrite design styles for the specified html element
      if (confirm("Their is already a design with that label ("+saveLabel+"). Overwrite this designs data for the given element/styles?")) {
           currentDesigns["saved_designs"][saveLabel]["class"] = saveClass;
           //edit other subdata here...
      }
 }else{//create new
      var newDesign = [];
      newDesign[saveLabel] = [];
      newDesign[saveLabel]["class"] = saveClass;
      newDesign[saveLabel]["style"] = [];
      newDesign[saveLabel]["hover"] = [];

      currentDesigns["saved_designs"].push(newDesign);//gives error..push is not defined
 }      
 jQuery("#'.$elementId.'").val(JSON.stringify(currentDesigns));
```

thanks in advance. Hope this is clear. Ill update accordingly based on questions and comments.
Shaun

Comment: This is javascript dynamically written via PHP...hence the jQuery("#'.$elementId.'") part....take this into account...there are no basic syntax errors.

Comment: In JavaScript `[]` declares an array with numbers as keys  while `{}` decdeclares an object. Objects have keys/properties that can be used like an array with named keys.

Comment: -2  what did i do?!?
Thanks Toni...given example above, this notation should be fine then.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted... Any who, you can use obj.hasOwnProperty("key") to check if a property exists and you can assign a new property or override an existing one with `obj.key=value` or `obj["key"]=value`. To update a value you can chain keys (e.g. `obj["key1"] ["key2"]=value`)Sorry if that isn't super relevant. I am on my phone and it is hard to follow longer questions. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit confusing. JavaScript objects look a lot like a **map** or a **dictionary** from other languages. You can iterate over them and access their properties with object['property_name'].

Thus the difference between a property and a string index doesn't really exist. That looks like php you are creating. It's called an array there, but the fact that you are identifying values by a string means it is going to be serialized into an *object* in javascript.

`var thing = {"saved_designs":{"label":{"class":"someclass","style":[],"hover":[]}}}`

`thing.saved_designs.label` is the same thing as `thing["saved_designs"]["label"]`.

In javascript an array is a list that can only be accessed by integer indices. Arrays don't have explicit keys and can be defined:

```
var stuff = ['label', 24, anObject]
```

So you see the error you are getting about 'push not defined' is because you aren't working on an array as far as javascript is concerned.

```
currentDesigns["saved_designs"] == currentDesigns.saved_designs
```

When you have an object, and you want a new key/value pair (i.e. property) you don't need a special function to add. Just define the key and the value:

```
**currentDesigns.saved_designs['key'] = newDesign;**
```

If you have a different label for every design (which is what it looks like) key is that label (a string).

---

Also when you were defining the new design this is what javascript interprets:

```
  var newDesign = [];
```

newDesign is an array. It has n number of elements accessed by integers indices.

```
  newDesign[saveLabel] = [];
```

Since newDesign is a an array saveLabel should be an numerical index. The value for that index is another array.

```
  newDesign[saveLabel]["class"] = saveClass;
  newDesign[saveLabel]["style"] = [];
  newDesign[saveLabel]["hover"] = [];
```

Here explicitly you show that you are trying to use an array as objects. Arrays do not support ['string_key']

This might very well 'work' but only because in javascript arrays are objects and there is no rule that says you can't add properties to objects at will. However all these [] are not helping you at all.

```
var newDesign = {label: "the label", class: saveClass};
```

is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: excellent thanks. Some good pointers in there...need to get back on and test this. Ill upvote...this should help (thing.saved_designs.label). Cant upvote...im on the wrong account! Created a second account by accident due to login errors  :(